limit in two variables (Polar Coordinates) lower bound
Let $A \subseteq \Bbb{R}^2$ be a finite connected subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ such that $(0,0)\in A$. Let $f:A \to \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be real-analytic. Moreover, suppose that $f$ has only one zero in $A$, namely $(0,0)$. Consider the polar coordinates of $f$. Specifically,
$$
\tilde{f}(r,\theta) = f(r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta)).
$$
Let $n_{\theta}$ be the smallest non-negative integer, such that for fixed $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$,
$$
\tilde{f}^{(n_{\theta})}(0,\theta) \ne 0.
$$
Additionally, suppose that $n_{\theta} \leq M$, $M$ finite. Lastly, let
$$
d(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.
$$
$\textbf{Claim.}$
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)}{d(x,y)^{M+1}} = \infty.
$$
$\textbf{Ideas.}$ Fix $\delta >0$. As $f$ is analytic, for $r<\delta$,
$$
\tilde{f}(r,\theta) \geq c_{\theta}r^{n_{\theta}},
$$
for some $c_{\theta}$ dependent on $\theta$ and $\delta$. Moreover, $c_{\theta} > 0$.
Now, let us consider the limit in question. Note that we can vary $\theta$ as $r\to 0$.
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)}{d(x,y)^{M+1}} \geq \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\tilde{f} (r,\theta)}{r^{M+1}} \geq \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{c_{\theta}r^{n_{\theta}}}{r^{M+1}} \geq \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{c_{\theta}r^{M}}{r^{m+1}}\geq \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{c_{\theta}}{r} = \infty,
$$
as $c_{\theta} > 0$ for all $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$.
$\textbf{Concerns.}$ I'm not convinced that my proof works. The following question is why: Polar Coordinates as a Definitive Technique for Evaluating Limits.
One of the answers shows that for (x,y) = (x,x^2),
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2} = \frac{1}{2},
$$
whereas a conversion to polar coordinates yields that
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r\cos{\theta}^2\sin{\theta}}{r^2\cos(\theta)^2+\sin(\theta)^2} = 0.
$$
Granted my problem isn't the exact same as my lower bound is $\infty$. Any thoughts/ideas would be greatly appreciated or a counterexample to my conjecture.
